# Asus Bios don't recognice ssd m.2 sata

Tags: laptop, ssd, bios, clone

I have an asus laptop M580VD, this model has a 256gb ssd m.2 sata. I bought a new ssd crucial MX500 1tb. I use an usb case to attach the new ssd to laptop and clone it. But, when I attach it to laptop, bios don't recognice it. I update the bios to last version and obtain the same result.

My bios only has two sata modes: Interl rst Premium and AHCI. The actual mode is intel one. I tried both with the new cloned ssd.

Do you have any suggestion? I am a bit lost.

**Solved**

It was a mechanical topic. I repeat the ssd clonation using Macrium Reflect software, because I repeat the replacement between new an old ssd, I prefer didnt close perfectly the laptop. Then, the new ssd was detected. Reviewing the laptop back, there is a kind of sponge that do presion in the base of the ssd, I comparate the old ssd and the new ones and this part is a bit thick. I move the sponge a bit and now my new disk work perfectly :).

Comment: write your answer separately and accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to install a new bios firmware?
https://www.asus.com/lk/Laptops/M580VD/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: Hi, I installed the last version avaible in the asus  website.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mechanical topic. I repeat the ssd clonation using Macrium Reflect software, because I repeat the replacement between new an old ssd, I prefer didnt close perfectly the laptop. Then, the new ssd was detected. Reviewing the laptop back, there is a kind of sponge that do presion in the base of the ssd, I comparate the old ssd and the new ones and this part is a bit thick. I move the sponge a bit and now my new disk work perfectly :).